# Client-Server connects while being on the same computer but not while being run on different ones

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm trying to build a basic client-server application. 
When I run both the server and the client on the same computer both manage to connect without a hitch but if I try to do so from different computers (desktop and laptop) the connection doesn't get though. The server isn't even aware that someone tried to connect to it while the client timeouts after a while. At first I assumed that it's a firewall problem but disabling the firewall completely on the server PC did not help. Tried changing ports and checked on multiple computers. Any ideas what could cause this?
I control both the server and the client and can change the code of both if necessary. The server always runs on the same PC and I'm connecting to it directly using hardcoded IP address.
This is the code of the client sending random int to the server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket s = new Socket();
    try {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("123.45.67.891", 8084), 5000);
        s.getOutputStream().write(42);
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }   
}
```

The server is slightly more complicated but considering the fact that they manage to connect while being run from the same PC I assume that the problem isn't with it.

edit: Server code (Thread per client. There shouldn't be too many of those)

```
public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(listenPort); //integer
    } catch (IOException e) { ... }
    while (shouldRun) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // Blocked here while trying to connect from remote computer   

//Never gets here   
            ConnectionHandler newConnection = connectionHandlerCreator.create(clientSocket);
            connectionHandlers.add(newConnection);
            newConnection.initialize();
            new Thread(newConnection).start();
        } catch (IOException e) { ... }
    }
}
```

Initialize consists of the following (which latter used for I/O).

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Comment: Check whether both are in same subnet. Also try to ping the address from the ends to ensure that they are pingable.

Comment: can you post at least the code of the line creating the serversocket ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on your server side though: you have to make it respond to all ip's not just local one, by using the constructor:

```
ServerSocket(int port)
```

it will default accepting connections on any addresses which is not the case if you specified an IP